# How to fix 'InvalidResourceType.NotSupportedError' for ECS using SDK for alibaba cloud?

Tags: node.js, alibaba-cloud-ecs

**I am trying to create an ECS instance using the Node SDK, but failing. I am not sure if I have done the right thing.
I am able to create the ECS with same configuration using Portal as well as ROS.**

```
//using the SDK for ECS
var ECSClient = require('@alicloud/ecs-2014-05-26');


// crearting the client
var client = new ECSClient({
    accessKeyId: 'myaccesskeyid',
    accessKeySecret: 'myaccesskeysecret',
    endpoint: 'https://ecs.aliyuncs.com'
});

// image id and instance type procured using the OpenApi explorer
var params = {
    ImageId: 'winsvr_64_dtcC_1809_en-us_40G_alibase_20190528.vhd',
    InstanceType: 'ecs.t1.xsmall',
    RegionId: 'ap-south-1'
}

// options
var opts = {
    'x-acs-region-id': "ap-south-1"
}

// calling the sdk method to create ecs instance
client.createInstance(params, opts).then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
}, (err) => {
    console.log('ERROR!!')
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but a suggestion. Create a support ticket in Portal. They replied pretty fast and solved my ECS problems.

Comment: Okay, Thank you. Will do.